# Prevent LaTeX from splitting footnotes across two pages

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, footmisc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Footnote runs onto second page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32208/footnote-runs-onto-second-page)

In my KOMA-Script document …

```
\documentclass[smallheadings,a4paper,twoside=false,12pt]{scrbook}
```

… I currently use the following header options related to footnotes:

```
% footnotes
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} 
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{1.1em}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter} % don't start count on chapters
```

My geometry is as follows:

```
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
```

On several pages, I get this undesirable output, where a footnote is split across two pages, even though there would be enough space to fit it on the first one:

[image]

Even though it's perfectly capable of allowing for more space:

[image]

So, how can I prevent it from breaking footnotes at *any time*?

Comment: There is actually *not* enough space to fit the footnote on one page. It's just a bad placement of the existing footnote marker - at the end of a page - coupled with a lengthy (for that location) footnote. One suggestion would be to modify the text to push the footnote over to the following page entirely (both the marker and the footnote text).

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined

Comment: @Werner Yeah, I inevitably have to include some paragraphs here and there to prevent fragments on a few pages, but since it happens a few times in this (lengthy) document, I'd rather get rid of it all ;)

Comment: @Werner. Is there a way to force LaTeX to detect and prevent such cases (i.e. of a marker placed too low on the page to avoid a split)? It would automatically pagebreak and move to the next page the line that contains the marker, in order to avoid a split footnote.

Comment: @VincentKrebs: It probably doesn't happen often enough for this to be a problem you can't fix manually. I don't know of any automated way.