# Producing a LaTeX warning when a footnote is split across several pages

Tags: footnotes

A long footnote occupying several lines sometimes gets split across several pages in the compiled document. Is it possible to generate a LaTeX warning when that happens?

A minimal working example can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32208/footnote-runs-onto-second-page): the context is similar, and all I want is a warning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [fnbreak](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnbreak) package, which generates the warning(s):

> fnbreak – Warn for split footnotes
>
> This package detects footnotes that are split over several pages, and writes a warning to the log file.

Comment: Great, thanks! Interestingly, this did not come up in a search engine when I tried something similar to the topic of this question.

Comment: I noticed that both "\usepackage{fnbreak}" and "\usepackage[nolabel]{fnbreak}" change the page layout a bit: in particular, my former split footnote is placed on the following page now.

I would guess that the action of this package gives "additional preference" to non-split footnotes (maybe not intentionally).